# Which API call creates new bitcoin addresses

Tags: api

If I have, say 20, priv/pub key pairs in my wallet which bitcoin API calls do I use to:

1. Select a specific privpub key pair.
2. Generate a new bitcoin address (using the selected private key)

Answer (score 1):

```
bitcoind getnewaddress [account]
```

Where `account` is the name you want the new address associated with.

Here is the [API documentation.](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list)

Comment: OK but getnewaddress does not take the private key as an argument. How do I create a new address using a selected private key?

Comment: There is no method which accepts a private key as input. However what you can do is take an address from a specific key from your wallet and then if you call `getnewaddress` with that account, the new address will be associated with that private key.

Comment: what if I only have one account that uses all the private keys how do I associate a new address with a specific key then?

Comment: you cant have an account associated with more then one key, however you can have as many accounts as you want associated with a given key.

Comment: but guys like blockchain.fino (which is a shared e-wallet) allows you to have a unique private key per user. I presume blockchain.info also only has one wallet on bitcoind with user accounts managed in a separate db. Thus if a user transfer funds from his account he uses his own private key to generate a unique address.

Comment: You can use things like [pywallet](https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet) to manage lots of different `wallet.dat` files. But the fact remains, a given account can only ever be associated with one `wallet.dat` file however each `wallet.dat` can have arbitrarily many accounts associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get your private keys, you have to:

1. Unlock your wallet if it is encrypted by calling: WalletPassphrase
2. Call ListReceivedByAddress with arguments: 0, true to get all available addresses
3. Iterate through those addresses and for each of them that you want to grab the key pair call DumpPrivKey

To get a new address just call the GetNewAddress method.